# jsf requiredMessage css

Tags: java, css, jsf, jsf-2

I want to apply style to my validation messages because as of right now they are by default red and apply themselves on the bottom left of the page. For instance when a user types in an empty username field, the message "username is required" appears, but it has a bullet before it and it and is red. I also have custom validators on some of my input fields.

```
<h:panelGrid class="grid" columns="2" id="regPanel">
        <h:form>

            <h:outputLabel class="outputLabel" value="Username"/>
            <h:inputText class="inputText" id="userNameInputText"
                         value="#{regBean.userName}" required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Username is required"  >

            </h:inputText>  .... more form inputs with required fields

        </h:form>

    </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Did you try get class css of validation messages and override that class ?

Comment: I am new to JSF. What I tried this<h:message for="username" class="validation" />. This worked, except it seemed very tedious to do this for each input and it did not work for my custom validators, no message showed up at all.

Comment: You can use Inspect element function of browser(such as Chrome) to get css class of validation message which you want to override css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to put `h:messages` or `h:message` tags in your view where you want to have the messages rendered. With `h:messages`, all the message of the page are rendered in a central list. With `h:message` you can just render the messages connected to one component like this:

```
<h:inputText id="long" value="#{bean.longValue}"/>
<h:message for="long"/>
```

The styling can be changed with various attributes on `h:messages` and `h:message`. There are attributes to set the style directly or a style class for each message severity (info, warn, error, fatal). The style can be set like this:

```
<h:message for="long" warnStyle="color: green" infoStyle="color: blue"
    errorClass="errorMsg" fatalClass="fatalMsg"/>
```

There is not standard way for "re-use" of the style classes. You would have to put them on each tag without modifications. But there are several ways this could be achieved:

1. Build a composite component for messages with default styling
2. Replace the renderer of the message component to support default styles
3. Use a component library like PrimeFaces

Answer (score 0):

You can use message, growl of Primefaces. and you can get css class of validation message and override it.
For example: i changed css of growl message:

```
<style type="text/css">
                .ui-growl-image.ui-growl-image-error{
                    background-image: none !important;
                    background-color: navy;
                }
            </style>
```

Demo:http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/messages.jsf

If you use default message of JSF, you must add css class to each component or create your own component.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'get css class of validation message'. When I go to view source all the messages are under the id '#javax_faces_developmentstage_messages' which when I try to add in my css does not override anything.